# how to add default variants to product in magento

Tags: magento

I'm very new to  **Magento**.I am having product with some variants  like "*size*" with values "*large XX,small XX,medium XX*".I want the feature to make any one of this values as default in admin.

my screenshot explanation [here](http://www.diigo.com/item/image/19c1l/p7sj)

How can i do this

please help me!

Answer (score 1):

When you say you want them to be defaults, you are being a little vague. Are you talking about using configurable products for this? Custom product options? When you say "default in admin", what do you mean? Which page are you referring to? More detail will help us answer the question.

Thanks,
Joe

---

As far as I know, what you are asking for is not a default functionality of Magento, but it shouldn't be difficult to add some javascript to allow you to force selections at page load time. Ultimately, it's just code, so it's definitely possible to do.

Comment: Mastly:please review my screenshot. I need  option to select any one variance as default in admin.is this posible

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion would be to add a attribute to all you products called for instance "defaultselect" then you can enter your value easily from the backend to your configurable product.

so now you have a configurable product say a hat which comes in 3 sizes, and has 3 assigned simple products. set the defaultselect value to  one of the size values

now some layout xml and javascript is required to get you product attribute to work with the magento selects.

first you want to actually include you js. this is done through the layout xml.  you can include update using add js method for PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable handle
now the js. store the js in the skin js folder.

to make this work you would need to  know the configurable product defaultselect attribute value we're testing against. this could be retrieved with your own ajax function to a method which checks if the current product has a defaultselect attribute and returns it's value or false.

if you have a value from your ajax function you can work with that ie you have both the returned attributes from the configurable product and magento will return the rest.
however after that it seems to get complicated your going to have to do something with the js magento aready uses to render product options